# Simple bar-chart with y-axis in percent

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw several but very similiar horizontal and vertical bar charts like the ones I show at the end. They are very simple even primitive to do in libreoffice Calc or Excel but none of the solutions I found so far in the internet do exactly what I want. Even going through the pgfplots manual did not help me in the end. The closest I got was from code I read here and that I think should be possible to adjust to get the solution.

The differences are first: that the data here are calculated into percentages whereas I want to type in percentage values right away; second: that I think there is no need to write the values on top of each bar and third: that the Name of the scenarios should be placed in the middle of the two bars (like in the picture).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Category 1,6,0,0
Category 2,2,2,0
Category 3,3.5,2.5,4
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/expr={
    \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
}
]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
every node near coord/.append style={
    align=center,
    text width=1cm
},
    nodes near coords={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
    \ifnum\iszero=0
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    \fi},
nodes near coords align=vertical,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100,table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
percentage plot,ybar,bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge x limits=0.25,
symbolic x coords={Category 1,Category 2,Category 3},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt through code you have tried so far? You can input percentage values like `20, 55` etc and the use `yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick\,\percent}$},`

Comment: The link above provides the code – i just changed category 1, category 2, category 3 to the Scenarios Election, Biology, Shell Game and of course I changed the values.

Comment: Why don't you post that code so that we can save some clicks and modifications? ;)

Comment: Did it! Sorry but I lost my edited code. I tried to get a result like the second image I posted…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following, you can directly enter the percentage values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Scenarios Election,60,10,30
Biology,20,55,22
Shell Game,35,25,40
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/expr={
    \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
}
]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
every node near coord/.append style={
    align=center,
    text width=1cm
},
    nodes near coords={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
    \ifnum\iszero=0
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    \fi},
nodes near coords align=vertical,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
ylabel=Responses in Percent,
xlabel=Scenario,
percentage plot,
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge x limits=0.25,
symbolic x coords={Scenarios Election, Biology, Shell Game},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
\legend{mono,multi,many}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Cleaned up version will be as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Scenarios Election,60,10
Biology,20,55
Shell Game,35,25
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
nodes near coords align=vertical,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
ylabel=Responses in Percent,
xlabel=Scenario,
percentage plot,
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge x limits=0.25,
symbolic x coords={Scenarios Election, Biology, Shell Game},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\legend{mono,multi}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the `xbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Scenarios Election,60,10
Biology,20,55
Shell Game,35,25
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    enlarge x limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={x \as \originalvalue}
},
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
xlabel=Responses in Percent,
ylabel=Scenario,
percentage plot,
xbar=0pt,
bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge y limits=0.25,
every axis y label/.append style={yshift=1.8cm},
symbolic y coords={Scenarios Election, Biology, Shell Game},
ytick=data
]
\addplot table [x index = 1, y index = 0] {\data};
\addplot table [x index = 2, y index = 0] {\data};
\legend{mono,multi}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without percentage signs and variable y range:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Scenarios Election,6,2,3
Biology,1,5,2
Shell Game,2,4,3
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=7,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
ylabel=Responses in Percent,
xlabel=Scenario,
percentage plot,
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge x limits=0.25,
symbolic x coords={Scenarios Election, Biology, Shell Game},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
\legend{mono,multi,many}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I get rid of the numbers on top of the bars, too? And: is a horizontal chart bar possible with just some adjustments of the code?

Comment: Again: Thank you! I want to learn how to do that, too!

Comment: One last question: what would I have to change if instead of the percentages on the y-axis I want numbers from 1 to 7?

Comment: @PeterStrawson: See the latest edits for `xbar`. By `1-7` you mean no `%` signs needed?

Comment: Exactly! not needed and not wanted. I am going to study your code later to learn how it is done. This is brilliant!

Comment: @PeterStrawson OK. Are your y values lie between 1 to 7? Or do you want to normalize them?

Comment: Sorry – they lie in between 1 and 7. But that  is just an example. Sometimes they lie in between 1 and 4. I don’t want to normalize them.

Comment: @PeterStrawson See the last edit. You can change `ymax` values as desired.

Comment: That is it! I guess that I am smart enough to find out how to transform the last one to an xbar. I am stunned how fast you could solve my problems. Thanks again!

Comment: @PeterStrawson Glad to be of help. Please don't forget that you can upvote and accept answers as a token of thanks. :)